# System Load Indicator only shows as a line unless hovered

Tags: 18.04, indicator, gnome-shell

I installed the [System Load Indicator](https://launchpad.net/indicator-multiload) GNOME extension on my Ubuntu 18.04, but for some reason, instead of showing a proper graph for CPU usage, it only shows a very thin line that seems to be a small portion of the actual graph. If I hover over it, the proper graph shows. How to make it show the whole graph all the time?

[image]
[image]

Comment: package indicator-multiload is also not supported on 19.04 as it just flashes on that same desktop top status bar widget

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Although [System Load Indicator](https://launchpad.net/indicator-multiload) (`indicator-multiload`) works well with desktop environments like Unity, MATE etc., it's not *very* compatible with GNOME 3 (default in Ubuntu 17.10 and later).

If you want to try an alternative solution which is compatible with GNOME, you may use a [GNOME shell extension](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions) called "[**system-monitor**](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/120/system-monitor/)". It does

> Display system informations in gnome shell status bar, such as memory usage, cpu usage, network rates…
>
> [image]

You can also install it from the '*Software*' application or by running

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-system-monitor
```

Comment: Is there a way to increase the size of the font? On my computer it looks like 9pt if not just 8 or even 7. It's like tiny. White on black which becomes light gray because of the anti-aliasing and it becomes really hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

or until (if ever) they fix it, you could try:
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-usage
which, yes, doesn't do tray at the moment

Comment: If you just wish to use an application (instead of a tray icon/indicator) to monitor various system-resource info, then you don't even need to install any other extra application. Ubuntu releases comes with a pre-installed System Monitor.