# Why does 'Open System Monitor' in Parrot OS differ from Ubuntu?

Tags: gnome-shell, system-monitor

I notice that both OSes are using the same '*Open System Monitor*'.

However, the one I installed on Ubuntu only has 1 indicator while Parrot has 3 for CPU, Memory and HDD/SSD utilization.

Picture description:

- Left (VirtualBox Guest is Parrot)
- Right (VirtualBox Guest is Ubuntu)

  [image]

Would it be possible to have similar outlook on Ubuntu?

This is the setting of '*Open System Monitor*' in Ubuntu.

[image]

Comment: From your screenshots it seems you're using GNOME 3 desktop environment (default in Ubuntu 17.10 and later). The 'system monitor indicator' (`indicator-applet`) is not *very* compatible with GNOME, whereas Parrot OS uses MATE desktop environment, with which `indicator-applet` works well. Possible duplicate of [System Load Indicator only shows as a line unless hovered](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036618/system-load-indicator-only-shows-as-a-line-unless-hovered)